# Retrieve only hour from Timestamp field stored in DB

Tags: java, database, oracle, timestamp

I have a table with differents fields. Some are String, others are Timestamp(6) in DB.
The issue is when I display data from this table, I got this for the Timestamp fields:

> 15/12/10 00:03:00,000000000

I would like to store and display only hour like this:

> 00:03:00

Nothing else.
I retrieve the data from DB via a web method in java. I'm using Hibernate with DAO pattern.

What changes I have to do ? 
There is a method to extract only hour maybe ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use [**EXTRACT()**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) function.

For example,

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSDATE) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I need to make it in Java side.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) || ':' ||EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)|| ':' ||EXTRACT(SECOND FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM Demo;
```

OR

```
to_char(cast(SYSDATE as date),'hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: I need to make it in Java side.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can use the [to_char(...)](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) function on the SQL side, which will return the hour directly

```
SELECT to_char(t.my_date, 'hh24') FROM mytable t;
```

If you dont want to use this you can use [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) on Java side. In this minimal working example you query the data from your table an extract the hour from the timestamps.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;

public final class StackOverFlowExmaple {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("registering oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver did not work");
        }

        final String dbUser = "", dbPasswd = "", dbHost = "", dbPort = "", dbSid = "";
        final String connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:" + dbUser + "/" + dbPasswd + "@//" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbSid;

        final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        final Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

        final ResultSet resultset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT t.my_timestamp FROM my_table t;");

        while (resultset.next()) {
            final Timestamp tStamp = resultset.getTimestamp(0);
            final long time = tStamp.getTime();
            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            System.out.println("hour: " + hour);
        }

        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to make it in Java side.
I've a class with Date fields according to Timestamp fields in DB, so I do not really know how to use what you wrote for java.

Comment: I now changed my post to an minimal working example, I hope you now know where start :-)